# Git count filtered commits

Tags: git, count, grep, git-commit, commit-message

Is it possible to get a number of git commits filtered by commit-message?

```
$ git log --all --grep='SEARCH_STRING'
```

With this snippet I get a list of all commits with the searched string.
But I got a lot of commits and its hard to count this by Hand.

Is there a way git tells me the sum of the commits in this list?

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the expected output given an input? Not exactly sure what you mean by 'sum of commits in this list'

Comment: Hi @Inian. I just want to get the number of commits that matches the given string in commit message.

Comment: Doesn't `git log --all --grep='SEARCH_STRING' --count` work? or even `git log --all --grep='SEARCH_STRING' | wc -l` ?

Comment: the first one gives just the list again.
The second counts the numbers of lines in this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it

```
$ git rev-list --all --grep='SEARCH_STRING' --count
```

Thanks to @Inian for the tip with --count.

Comment: That's the right answer (well, one of several possible ones, but the one I would use). In general, if you have a `git log` command that you want to turn into some sort of scripting thing, you just replace `log` with `rev-list`. They mostly have the same options from that point forward, but `log` shows commits to a user, while `rev-list` simply lists their hash IDs. Adding `--count` replaces the list of hash IDs with counts of hash IDs (usually one count, but see `--left-right` and symmetric difference; this gets you two counts).

Comment: Cool comment learned a lot from it as always, like any other post or comment by torek